# Can I Assassinate my queen?

Tags: medieval-2-total-war

I'm playing Medieval 2: Total War and my king has `cuckold` as one of his many attributes.  `Cuckold` reduces his authority by two.  Given that he is the king and has assassins at his disposal, this has raised the question of whether it is possible to assassinate or otherwise "deal with" this troublesome spouse?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can't. Queens (and princesses once they are married off), don't appear as characters on the campaign map, so there is no way to interact with them (such as with the pointy end of an assassin).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assasinate your queen, in fact, you can assasinate just the princesses on the map(active,not married),just if they are from other countries. So,no you can't assasinate your queen. Better let her pass away.